# How to set up a serial connection to a Windows 7 computer

Tags: windows-7, serial, dial

I need to set up a "dial in" connection to a Windows 7 (Ultimate) computer via a serial null-modem cable to be able to connect from a Windows XP client to that computer and exchange data over IP.

**Question 1:** How do I do that?

I did neither find the information via Google nor in the MSDN. Seems like no one tried ever before... ;-)

I already managed to install a legacy modem device called **"Communications cable between two computers"** and found the menu entry **"New Incoming Connection..."** in *Network and Internet > Network Connections*. When I finish this wizard I get the message that the "Routing and Remote Access service" cannot be started. In the event viewer I see the following error messages:

- "The currently configured authentication provider failed to load and initialize successfully. The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found." (Source: RemoteAccess, EventID: 20152)
- "The Routing and Remote Access service terminated with service-specific error The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found." (Source: Service Control Manager, EventID: 7024)

**Question 2:** Am I on the right path to set up the connection?

**Question 3:** How can I get the Routing and Remote Access service running?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the issue has something to do with proper initialization of TCP/IP stack:

When I establish an Ethernet connection first, the Routing and Remote Access service starts without problems, even if the Ethernet connection is terminated before.

So this is the answer to **question 3**.

The answer to **question 1 and 2** is (in case anyone is interested in):

- Install the legacy modem device "Communications cable between two computers" via *Device Manager*'s menu "Actions" > Add legacy hardware.
- Go to "view Network Connections" (only available via search field in start menu!), and select "New Incoming Connection..." from the "File" menu (which appears after pressing ALT). Follow the wizard and adjust the settings.
- **Done! :)**

Comment: This answer is right on.  I was getting the same error about the RemoteAccess service not starting when I was trying to add an Incoming Connection for a modem on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.  Connected the network cable and tried again and it worked without error. Unfortunately, without leaving the network cable attached, the Incoming Connection does not persist upon reboot.

Comment: I asked about persisting the connection and received a quick answer.  Install a Microsoft Loopback Adaptor device and all the networking stuff will initialize properly. http://serverfault.com/a/634243/1164

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor: get laplink. It's not free but it's pretty cheap and it will do what you want.

Comment: I do not need a tool to transfer data (laplink), I need an IP connection via serial cable.