# How to set up Incoming Connection over modem for offline Windows 7 system

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7, modem

I have a Windows 7 computer that will be offline except for a modem connection.

From a [previous question](https://serverfault.com/q/130435/1164) I have worked around an error setting up the Incoming Connection.  (The RemoteAccess service could not start unless a network connection was already established)

However when I remove the network connection and reboot, the connection does not persist.  From the previous answer, I'm hoping that if I can find a way to intialize the TCP stack when the computer boots up, despite there being no network connection available, my modem's Incoming Connection will show up as a network connection and I'll be able to dial in.

How to get the stack to initialize properly, or how to otherwise work around this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to add a loopback adapter to the machine to enable the functionality you're looking for:

- Start / `hdwwiz.exe`
- Choose "Install the hardware that I manually select from a list (Advanced)"
- Choose "Network adapters"
- Choose "Microsoft" in the "Manufacturer" pane and "Microsoft Loopback Adapter" in the "Network Adapter:" pane
- Complete the installation

Once the loopback adapter is installed you may need to assign a static IP address to get the functionality you're looking for w/ Routing and Remote Access.

Comment: Glad I could help! Loopback adapters are useful things.